# For loop with an else and one iteration

Tags: python-3.x, for-else

I have a `for loop` that loops through a dynamic list of contact objects, and checks if the contact email meets a specified condition. I used an `else` statement with the `for loop` to return a "Sorry condition not met", when the list is exhausted. This approach works fine except when the list has only **one** contact, which satisfies the condition. In this scenario, both the body of the `for loop` and the `else` portions are executed.

Kindly advise on how to let the interpreter ignore the `else` part for one iteration that meets the set condition.

```
def searchContact(self, search_name):
    print("Your search matched the following:")
    for contact in self.contacts:
        if search_name in contact.name:
            print(contact)
    else:
        print("Sorry that contact does not exist!!")
```

Comment: That `else` clause will *always* be executed. An `else` on a loop executes if the loop ends without `break`ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user2357112 mentions, and as stated in the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

> a loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs

You could try something along the lines of:

```
def searchContact(self, search_name):
    contact_found = False

    print("Your search matched the following:")
    for contact in self.contacts:
        if search_name in contact.name:
            contact_found = True
            print(contact)

    if not contact_found:
        print("Sorry that contact does not exist!!")
```